# Packaging dozer library jars in EAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, dozer

My EAR structure is similar to below.

- My EAR

  - META-INF
  - lib

    - ..some jars...
    - dozer-*.jar
  - My WAR1

    - WEB-INF

      - classes

        - ...classes for which dozer mapping is required...
        - dozer-mapping.xml
    - web.xml
  - My WAR2
  - ....

With this setup i'm getting an exception that dozer is not able to resolve my mapping classes defined in My WAR1/WEB-INF/classes/

What is the correct way/location to keep the dozer libraries, EAR/lib or WAR/WEB-INF/lib and why? Appreciate your response on this.

Answer (score 0):

Location of dozer libraries seems ok. Probably you have faced with `class isolation`. Classes of WAR1 module are isolated from classes of WAR2 module. Classes are loaded by different class loaders and are not visible by different modules. Usually this feature is configurable by app server.

This is not clear from your question what module initializers `Dozer` but it seems you need dozer mapper instance per module.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Am using spring config xml file in war1 to initialize dozer mapper and mapper instance is auto wired in my service classes. Also at this point I don't need dozer features on war2. I tried packaging dozer jars under war1/web-inf/lib and it worked. However I'm still not sure why it didn't work if I keep the dozer jars in ear/lib.